# Exporting Spring @Bean objects using JMX

Tags: java, spring, annotations, jmx

I'm using Spring's `@Configuration`, and I noticed that a `@Bean` does not get registered using JMX.

The bean is wired as

```
@Bean
protected CountingHttpInterceptor countingHttpInterceptor() {

    return new CountingHttpInterceptor();
}
```

and the class definition is

```
@ManagedResource
public class CountingHttpInterceptor implements HttpRequestInterceptor, HttpResponseInterceptor { /* code here*/ }
```

This `@Configuration` file is processed after the main , XML-based, application context is built, and does not have the chance to take part in the discovery process which is activated using XML bean definitions ( `org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationJmxAttributeSource` and frieds ).

How can I JMX-enable the beans from the `@Configuration` file?

---

*Update*: the xml configuration

```
<bean id="jmxExporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
    <property name="assembler" ref="assembler"/>
    <property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy"/>
    <property name="autodetect" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmxAttributeSource" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationJmxAttributeSource"/>

<bean id="assembler" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler">
    <property name="attributeSource" ref="jmxAttributeSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="namingStrategy" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.MetadataNamingStrategy">
    <property name="attributeSource" ref="jmxAttributeSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: This should work fine (it does for me, at least). Can you post the parts of your XML config that do the work here?

Comment: @skaffman: updated, but please note that this @Configuration class does _not_ participate in the parent XML application context. Rather, it is built as a separate application context, and has the XML-based app context set as a parent. Using Spring 3.0.2.RELEASE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything you have is correct.  In your @Configuration class you need to add one more annotation to export your MBeans, @EnableMBeanExport.

Your configuration class would look something like this...

```
@Configuration
@EnableMBeanExport
public class SpringConfiguration {
   @Bean
   protected CountingHttpInterceptor countingHttpInterceptor() {
      return new CountingHttpInterceptor();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Despite the temptations of the `@Configuration`- based approach, some things remain better done with XML config. In particular, the namespace-based config such as `<context:mbean-export>`. These essentially represent "macros" consisting of complex arrangements of interacting objects.

Now, you *could* replicate this logic in your `@Configuration` class, but it's really more trouble than it's worth.  Instead, I suggest putting such system-level stuff into XML, and importing it from your `@Configuration` class:

```
@ImportResource("/path/to/beans.xml")
public class MyConfig {
   @Bean
   protected CountingHttpInterceptor countingHttpInterceptor() {
      return new CountingHttpInterceptor();
   }
}
```

and then in `/path/to/beans.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
           xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
           ">  

    <context:mbean-export/>
</beans>
```

Comment: should be `public class MyConfig {` not `public lass MyConfig {`. Otherwise, thank you! :)