# How can Spring WebSocketMessageBrokerStats be exposed via JMX using MBeanExporter

Tags: spring, jmx, stomp, spring-websocket

Spring documentation say that when you use the @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker annotation, one bean of type WebSocketMessageBrokerStats es created. This bean can be exported to JMX through Spring’s MBeanExporter for viewing at runtime, for example through JDK’s jconsole (or VisualVM). I don't know how create the Mbean.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-stats

I found that `@EnableMBeanExport` is equivalent to use `<context:mbean-export>`

In another stackoverflow link I found that I need do some similar to the next:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMBeanExport

    public class SpringConfiguration {
       @Bean
       protected CountingHttpInterceptor countingHttpInterceptor() {
          return new CountingHttpInterceptor();
       }
    }
```

[Exporting Spring @Bean objects using JMX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133106/exporting-spring-bean-objects-using-jmx)

then I supposed that I need declare a bean as next:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMBeanExport
public class SpringConfiguration {

       @Bean
       protected WebSocketMessageBrokerStats webSocketMessageBrokerStats() {
           return new WebSocketMessageBrokerStats();
       }
 }
```

but this don't worked.

I found that I need enable JMX in the JVM too.
I'm using WildFly 9.0 as webapplication server.  I need enable the JMX to WebSocketMessageBrokerStats can work?

Actually I have a STOMP over Websocket implementation using Spring Framework 4.3.2. An Websocket WebSocketMessageBrokerStats show me the stats bean show information each 30 minutes in the console.

The unique place that I found some code using this Object is a Websocket Chat, but I don't understand how use it in the example.

https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve the problem.

Since this is a problem using Spring Framework I used the annotations that provide this framework.

1. Create a class where we need inject the `WebSocketMessageBrokerStats` bean that the `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` annotation create to monitor the websockets connections. We need annotate this class with `@ManagedResource`.

Code:

```
package mx.config.ws;
@ManagedResource(objectName = "Examples:type=JMX,name=Resource")                
public class WebSocketStatsJmxImpl implements WebSocketStatsJmx {


    public WebSocketStatsJmxImpl() {
        super();
        System.out.println("WebSocketStatsJmxImpl::Constructor");
    }



    WebSocketMessageBrokerStats webSocketMessageBrokerStats;

    public WebSocketMessageBrokerStats getWebSocketMessageBrokerStats() {
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setWebSocketMessageBrokerStats(WebSocketMessageBrokerStats webSocketMessageBrokerStats) {
        this.webSocketMessageBrokerStats = webSocketMessageBrokerStats; 
    }



    @ManagedAttribute(description="Get stats about WebSocket sessions.")                            // defines an attribute of an MBean
    public String getWebSocketSessionStatsInfo(){
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats.getWebSocketSessionStatsInfo();
    }
    @ManagedAttribute(description="Get stats about STOMP-related WebSocket message processing.")
    public String getStompSubProtocolStatsInfo(){
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats.getStompSubProtocolStatsInfo();
    }
    @ManagedAttribute(description="Get stats about STOMP broker relay (when using a full-featured STOMP broker).")
    public String getStompBrokerRelayStatsInfo(){
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats.getStompBrokerRelayStatsInfo();
    }
    @ManagedAttribute(description="Get stats about the executor processing incoming messages from WebSocket clients.")
    public String getClientInboundExecutorStatsInfo(){
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats.getClientInboundExecutorStatsInfo();
    }
    @ManagedAttribute(description="Get stats about the executor processing outgoing messages to WebSocket clients.")
    public String getClientOutboundExecutorStatsInfo(){
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats.getClientOutboundExecutorStatsInfo();
    }
    @ManagedAttribute(description="Get stats about the SockJS task scheduler.")
    public String getSockJsTaskSchedulerStatsInfo(){
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats.getSockJsTaskSchedulerStatsInfo();
    }
}
```

2. Create an @Configuration where we will create a Spring Bean where we instantiate the WebSocketStatsJmxImpl class. We must remember add the 
   @EnableMBeanExport in some place to registers with the JMX Agent all components annotated with the `@ManagedResource`.
   When we deploy the application, automatically all the configuration will be loaded and as we has the  @EnableMBeanExport declared into one @Configuration then the @EnableMBeanExport classes will be MBeans.

That's all :)

```
@Configuration
@EnableMBeanExport
public class WebSocketStatsJMXBeans {
    @Bean
    public WebSocketStatsJmxImpl jmxWebSocketStatsJmxImpl() {
        return new WebSocketStatsJmxImpl();
    }
}
```

In my case I use Eclipse + Wilfly pluging + Wildfly 9.0.

3. Open the Java VisualVM and look for "org.jboss.modules.main", go to MBeans tab and look in this case for Examples Mbean.

[image]

Thats all. This work.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring 5 and Spring Boot 2 it is possible to do it simpler.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Java JMX class to export:

```
@Component
@ManagedResource(objectName = "Examples:type=JMX,name=Resource")                
public class YourClassToExport {

    private WebSocketMessageBrokerStats webSocketMessageBrokerStats;

    public WebSocketMessageBrokerStats getWebSocketMessageBrokerStats() {
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setWebSocketMessageBrokerStats(WebSocketMessageBrokerStats webSocketMessageBrokerStats) {
        this.webSocketMessageBrokerStats = webSocketMessageBrokerStats; 
    }

    // attributes of an MBean

    @ManagedAttribute(description="Get stats about WebSocket sessions.")                            
    public String getWebSocketSessionStatsInfo(){
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats.getWebSocketSessionStatsInfo();
    }

    @ManagedAttribute(description="Get stats about STOMP-related WebSocket message processing.")
    public String getStompSubProtocolStatsInfo(){
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats.getStompSubProtocolStatsInfo();
    }

    @ManagedAttribute(description="Get stats about STOMP broker relay (when using a full-featured STOMP broker).")
    public String getStompBrokerRelayStatsInfo(){
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats.getStompBrokerRelayStatsInfo();
    }

    @ManagedAttribute(description="Get stats about the executor processing incoming messages from WebSocket clients.")
    public String getClientInboundExecutorStatsInfo(){
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats.getClientInboundExecutorStatsInfo();
    }

    @ManagedAttribute(description="Get stats about the executor processing outgoing messages to WebSocket clients.")
    public String getClientOutboundExecutorStatsInfo(){
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats.getClientOutboundExecutorStatsInfo();
    }

    @ManagedAttribute(description="Get stats about the SockJS task scheduler.")
    public String getSockJsTaskSchedulerStatsInfo(){
        return webSocketMessageBrokerStats.getSockJsTaskSchedulerStatsInfo();
    }

}
```